# Unknown javascript script scrolldown when enter page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have problem with unknown javascript script which scrolldown when enter page (I think it's javascript). I trying to find over firebug, code, delete scripts, I even deleted all styles,scripts, and had a clean code.

When enter this page **only in chrome browser** its scroll down to comments div, I have no idea why only chrome, firefox it's not do this, I have tested 2 computers them both the same on chrome.

This is the link of the page:

http://test.ibids.co.il/add/120

Which script do it or what cause to do this?

**EDIT 1 (27/01) :**  I don't think it's js as I have removed all JS from code.

**EDIT 1 (27/01) :**  It wad addthis script problem.

Comment: have you tried disabling all javascript files and enabling them one-by-one to maybe find the problematic file?

Comment: Yes. and its happened only on chrome, other browsers working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant comment so I will post answer. I have disabled all JS on site and still on reload page site was goes scroll down and then goes up so maybe it is not so JS related?

Comment: I did it too, and its happened only in chrome browser i cant figure why

Comment: Have you tried to leave JS but disable CSS and try if it jumps?

Comment: Did you saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571844/chrome-vertical-jump-when-refreshing-page-scrolled-to-bottom

Comment: yes i remove styles too same scroll down, now i will check the link. but the link you give me , he know what cause to the jump, i don't know.

Comment: I would try to disable html element by element starting from footer.

Comment: I would say that somehow problem is caused by addthis.com plugin. Could you disable it and try?

Comment: I removed each script on the blade.php, nothing cause the problem.

Comment: Oh my god, its was addthis -.-, i give it second chance... i already try it before but now when remove its good............ thanks man... now i dont know who to give 100 rep as all really worked hard to find..

Comment: Well you shuld give it to someone, it would be sad if it just waste.

Answer (score 3):

Before you do anything else: check your imported scripts! You are importing jQuery three times! This might create unwanted side effects.

```
 http://test.ibids.co.il/assets/js/new_js/jquery-1.9.1.js
 http://test.ibids.co.il/assets/header-js/jquery-1.11.1.js
 http://test.ibids.co.il/assets/notification/js/jquery-ab8e840c3dad7ccf2deadb8c40d53bdb.js
```

There might be more scripts / css that are not needed. Check your assets.

Comment: Well that is good point, anyway, it happens also when you disable JS.

Comment: Yeah but it's hard to debug the JS if every method is defined numerous times ;)

Comment: also there is an error on line 14 in this last jQuery

Comment: I will now remove uneeded jquery versions . i really don't know what cause this, i will try chrome support

Answer (score 0):

I think you have code related to navigate or nicescrollers  in your script .First try to remove if you have any code related to **navigateble :true**  ,and If you work on **nicescrollers** try to resize them or comment to check it once